# How do you define a type class for a union of types?

Tags: scala, typeclass, dispatch

The problem I'm having is that I'm getting infinite recursion when I try to define a type class on a union.

```
trait Foo[A]:
  extension (a: A)
    def bar: String
```

Now suppose I have the following givens defined:

```
given Foo[Int] with ...

given Foo[String] with ...
```

Now I want to create a union

```
type Value = String | Int
```

and, of course, `Value` should be a member of the type class. But if I do this:

```
given Foo[Value] with
   extension (v: Value)
     def bar: String = v match
       case i: Int => i.bar
       case s: String => s.bar
```

the problem is that `i.bar` and `s.bar` call the `bar` that goes with `Value`, not with `Int` or `String`, and I end up with infinite recursion. And casting them doesn't help.

Because `bar` is an extension function, I'm not sure how to get `Foo[Int]` and `Foo[String]` so that I could make the calls directly. Is there a way out of this, or have I coded myself into a corner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
scala> given Foo[Value] with
     |    extension (v: Value)
     |      def bar: String = v match
     |        case i: Int => summon[Foo[Int]].bar(i)
     |        case s: String => summon[Foo[String]].bar(s)
     |
// defined object given_Foo_Value
```

Comment: That is exactly what I didn't know how to do. I realized extension function were syntactic sugar, but didn't realize I could explicitly provide the argument. Thanks!